# What constitutes "מאכיל ומשקה מלביש ומכסה מכניס ומוציא" in honoring parents?

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Here's the source ([Kiddushin 31b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.29.21?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta'amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Bereishit%20Rabbah&lang2=en) and Shu"A).

Comparing to Shabbos, for example, the 39 Melachot are extensively detailed and each spans tens of pages. However, for those 6 "Melachot" of Kibud Av, there are no details I could find. Both Rambam and Shu"A just recite this phrase in whole without elaborating.

1. While "מאכיל ומשקה ומלביש" are a bit more common, what constitutes the Melachah of מכסה, מכניס and מוציא?
2. Where can I find specifications of each one of the 6 actions mentioned?

Comment: R. [Yaakov Chaim Sofer](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/יעקב_חיים_סופר_(הנין)) has a good piece determining what constitutes ‘מכניס ומוציא’ in sefer on Masechet Kiddushim ‘Ohr Moshe’ (§27).

Comment: What part of the simple translation do you find difficult that you’d expect someone to expand upon?

Comment: @DonielF מכסה what? Of what? by what? for what? מוציא from where? why he's מוציא? What part of it you DO understand? There's no Gemmorah, Rambam or else about the details.

Comment: @AlBerko If you’re going to nitpick like that, מאכיל what? Only certain types of foods? Only certain days of the week? The simple translation of מוציא is to bring him out - what more are you looking for? Your father asks you to bring him out, you bring him out. Your father asks you to bring him in, you bring him in. What’s the problem?

Comment: @DonielF I stated in my question, why don't you say that about Shabbos, בורר is very simple, why all the fuss? You have books on Esrog pimples but nothing on details of מאכיל? Seems weird...

Comment: @AlBerko Where there are Halachos L’Moshe MiSinai, they’re discussed; Chazal didn’t make up the rules of ביד מיד אוכל מתוך פסולת regarding Borer - that’s the tradition passed down to them. Regarding Esrog pimples - is there actually that much said about them in Chazal, beyond the color and size? Once again, where there’s a tradition that it’s not as simple as it seems, that’s where the discussion lies.

Comment: @AlBerko If your question is “This seemingly simple topic has a lot on it, and this seemingly simple topic has nothing - what’s the difference?” then you should really be asking about דברי תורה עניים במקום אחד ועשירים במקום אחר. (I think I misquoted it, but that general idea.)